# php analitics with image, get current url requesting the image

Tags: php, image, analytics

currently im doing something like www.imagecounter.com/image/site.png how can all the website that request my image?

lets say i put it in 3 site

```
www.1.com/inhere
www.2.com/12312312
www.3.com/andhere/maybehere
```

how can i get above urls where my image are put?

ive tried something like

`$referrer = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : NULL;`

but it seems it returns `NULL` all the time. or maybe im doing it wrong.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

I'd go a different road here, serve the file using your favorite web server and parse the logs once in a while to extract the information.

Comment: hmm how can we do that? what is the name of the file that contains the request logs? can we do something like tail thefile.log ? but put it on a database or something? (apache)

Comment: you can hook up on logrotate and configure a particular access_log for a file within your webserver.

Comment: @AdamRamadhan you can do it with nginx web server. is it ok for you? if yes i can describe it

Comment: @Ramil Amr please do anything will do.